# How to use condition if and else on single textview to display the results

Tags: java, android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Sorry, I have a good time that I search the site without I find an answer;
My question is how to make the conditions to display only non-empty results
on single textview : id=t.

**data.json** file:

```
  {
    "interactions":
    [
         {
           "MDT1": "ACIDE ACETOHYDROXAMIQUE",
           "MDT2": "FER",
           "CI": "",
           "AD": "",
           "PE": "",
           "PC": "A prendre en compte Diminution de l'absorption digestive de ces deux medicaments par chelation du fer..."
         },
         {
           "MDT1": "ACETAZOLAMIDE",
           "MDT2": "ACIDE ACETYLSALICYLIQUE",
           "CI": "",
           "AD": "Association DECONSEILLEE Majoration des effets indesirables.....",
           "PE": "",
           "PC": ""
         },
         {
           "MDT1": "ACETAZOLAMIDE",
           "MDT2": "CARBAMAZEPINE",
           "CI": "",
           "AD": "",
           "PE": "Precaution d'emploi Surveillance clinique........",
           "PC": ""
         },
         {
           "MDT1": "CARBAMAZEPINE",
           "MDT2": "OLANZAPINE",
           "CI": "",
           "AD": "",
           "PE": "Precaution d'emploi Surveillance clinique, et si besoin, adaptation posologique de l'olanzapine. Risque de diminution des concentrations plasmatiques de l'olanzapine et de son efficacite therapeutique, par augmentation de son metabolisme hepatique par la carbamazepine.",
           "PC": ""
         }
    ]
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public SearchableSpinner mySpinner;
private SearchableSpinner mySpinner1;
public ArrayList<Interactions> world = new ArrayList<>();
public final ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
public final ArrayList<String> m2Strings = new ArrayList<>();
.....

 public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the Interactions Class
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://rabah.000webhostapp.com/data.txt");
            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("interactions");
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++ ) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                    Interactions worldpop = new Interactions();
                    worldpop.setMDT1(jsonobject.optString("MDT1"));
                    worldpop.setMDT2(jsonobject.optString("MDT2"));
                    worldpop.setPE(jsonobject.optString("PE"));
                    worldpop.setCI(jsonobject.optString("CI"));
                    worldpop.setAD(jsonobject.optString("AD"));
                    worldpop.setPC(jsonobject.optString("PC"));
                    world.add(worldpop);
                    // Populate spinner with mdts names
                    mStrings.add(jsonobject.optString("MDT1"));
                    m2Strings.add(jsonobject.optString("MDT2"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Spinner adapter
            mySpinner.setAdapter(new SimpleListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mStrings));

            mySpinner1.setAdapter(new SimpleListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,m2Strings));
        }}

 private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
            public void onItemSelected(View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView txtMDT1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MDT1);
                txtMDT1.setText("MDT1 : " + world.get(position).getMDT1());

                TextView txtMDT2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MDT2);
                txtMDT2.setText("MDT2 : " + world.get(position).getMDT2());


                String PE = world.get(position).getPE();
                String PC = world.get(position).getPC();
                String CI = world.get(position).getCI();
                String AD = world.get(position).getAD();

                if (PE!="")
                {
                    TextView txtPE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
                    txtPE.setText("PE : " + world.get(position).getPE());
                }else if (PC!="") {
                    TextView txtPc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
                    txtPc.setText("Pc : " + world.get(position).getPC());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="gr.escsoft.michaelprimez.searchablespinnerexamples.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <gr.escsoft.michaelprimez.searchablespinner.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:RevealEmptyText="Touch to select"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:ShowBorders="true"
        app:BordersSize="1dp"
        app:BoarderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:SpinnerExpandHeight="250dp"/>

    <gr.escsoft.michaelprimez.searchablespinner.SearchableSpinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mySpinner1"
        app:SpinnerExpandHeight="0dp"
        app:BoarderColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:BordersSize="1dp" app:ShowBorders="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:RevealEmptyText="Touch to select"
        app:SearchViewBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:RevealViewBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:DoneSearchTintColor="@android:color/white"
        app:StartSearchTintColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySpinner"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MDT1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySpinner1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MDT2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MDT1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MDT2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped if you should've explained the question more.

Still what I managed to understand is that you're working with the strings (in your case `PE` and `PC` are `String` objects).

So instead of checking `if(PE!="")` , you must use: `if(!PE.equals(""))`

Because while working with `Strings` the expression `object == value` must be replaced with `object.equals(value)`

It would be **better** if you **use this expression instead**
`if(PE!=null && !PE.equals(""))`

This would make sure that the string `PE` is properly initialized and has a value inside as well.

Comment: thank you very much; It works with !PE.equals(" ") and !Objects.equals(PE, "") –

Comment: Good to know @RabahBoulhares
It would be great if you mark my answer.